# subsetting a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am having a data frame like

```
players    games
-------    ------
roger     tennis
messi     football
agasi     tennis
```

Now I would like to get a data frame which contains only game = tennis like

```
player    games
roger     tennis
agasi     tennis
```

How can I extract the data frame contains only games = tennis using R Language?

Comment: Your data don't look like a vector to me. Care to show us some example data in R - paste your code data into your question.

Comment: This is what my data frame looks like

  player     game
1  roger   tennis
2  messi football
3  agasi   tennis

Comment: I wonder if the solution will contain `grepl`? :)

Comment: OK, I'll bite. Show me the output of `head(foo)` where `foo` is the object containing your data in R. If you show that, I promise to take a look. Otherwise I'm going to vote to close, because as it stands your Q is of very low quality. The fact that your Q has no votes and no answers yet my comment has 5 up-ticks attests to that. Please help us to help you.

Comment: @Ananth, edit your question, use the {} to make your code into chunks.

Comment: @Roman, Thanks for the hint. @Gavin I have edited the question. Hope that will give clear idea. Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ananth <- data.frame(players = c("roger", "messi", "agassi"), game = c("tennis", "football", "tennis"))
subset(ananth, game == "tennis")
```

I think you may benefit from reading [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf).